# WebClient Headers

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I am using WebClient to scraping google search.
all the time I getting "Cannot reach this page"
until I changed the User-Agent Header:

```
            string page = string.Format("https://www.google.com/search?q={0}&hl=en", my_stocks[order].Symbole+" stock");
            WebClient client = new WebClient ();
            client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)";
            string r = client.DownloadString(page);
```

but the html presented differently from when I searching the same thing in my chrome.
so I tried change the header to the same when I use chrome with https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent
but getting "Cannot reach this page" again.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents ...

Since the influx of Single-Page-Applications, web scraping isn't what it used to be as pages are generally not server-side rendered any more.

It's highly likely that a Google Search is delivered using asynchronous REST queries, rather than a server-side rendered page.

Watch the Network trace in your Chrome tab when you do a Google search and you'll likely see many different network requests.

I suggest that you look for a more specific API to deal with the type of request that you're looking to make.